# How to cross compile bpf targets for linux arm on Mac M-series laptop?

Tags: linux, macos, clang, cross-compiling, ebpf

I am trying to discover and run a simple `eBPF` application on a local Linux VM on my Mac M1 laptop. For better efficiency, I chose to run an `arm`-based Ubuntu on UTM(an opensource VMM).

However, I am having trouble with compiling `eBPF` `elf` files. The most common way that I found on various tech blogs to compile is

```
clang -I headers -O -target bpf -c bpf/xdp.c -o bpf/xdp.elf
```

Personally, I try to use Mac clang to cross compile with target `bpf-linux-eabi`, but seems like the clang in Mac does not support this kind of target

```
error: unable to create target: 'No available targets are compatible with triple "bpf-unknown-linux-eabi"'
```

And `clang -print-targets` shows that

```
  Registered Targets:
    aarch64    - AArch64 (little endian)
    aarch64_32 - AArch64 (little endian ILP32)
    aarch64_be - AArch64 (big endian)
    arm        - ARM
    arm64      - ARM64 (little endian)
    arm64_32   - ARM64 (little endian ILP32)
    armeb      - ARM (big endian)
    thumb      - Thumb
    thumbeb    - Thumb (big endian)
    x86        - 32-bit X86: Pentium-Pro and above
    x86-64     - 64-bit X86: EM64T and AMD64
```

Obviously no `bpf` target found. BTW The `clang` version of Mac Ventura is `14.0`.

I also tried to find a Docker clang image, only `linux/amd64` versions are available(I need `linux/arm64`).

Anyone help to figure out how to cross compile elf files on Mac? Either by Mac `clang` or docker `clang`. Thank you in advance.

Comment: the binary installed by `brew install llvm` is located at `/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/clang`, which should be used instead

Comment: Hey Ziyan, have you managed to fix this issue? I haven't come across any articles explaining how to run ebpf on a Mac M1. I've tried using vagrant, docker, and virtualbox, but none of them seem to be working. Do you happen to have a list of steps for setting this up? I would really appreciate it if you could share a blog post or a github repository that discusses running ebpf on a Mac M1. Thank you! @ziyan-li

Answer (score 1):

When clang is compiled you can chose which targets are included or not. Your distro likely compiled clang without BPF support so you might have to manually compile clang instead.

Here is the getting started page which instructions on how to do so https://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html

There are a bunch of knobs during compilation the important ones found [here](https://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html#frequently-used-cmake-variables) especially important in your case is to make sure `BPF` is included in `LLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD` which controls this list of compiled in target platforms.